# PowerShell New-GPLink is giving the errors on cross domains

Tags: powershell, cross-domain

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to link my GPOs to several OUs on multiple domains. The issue I am having is with the New-GPLink cmdlet. When I run the command I get different errors. I can create and link GPOs in all domains in GPMC.

My domain is setup as a Forest with two domains under it (lets call them DomA and DomB). Then I have a third domain not under that forest (lets call it DomC).

My computer is in DomA and my account is in DomC.
The GPO is created in DomA and well call it GPO_Test_1.
The OU I want to link is at ou=Test,ou=GPO Testing,dc=DomA

If I run:

```
New-GPLink -Name "GPO_Test_1" -Target "ou=Test,ou=GPO Testing,dc=DomA" -LinkEnabled Yes
```

I get this error:

```
New-GPLink : The "GPO_Test_1" GPO was not found in the DomC domain.
Parameter name: gpoDisplayName
At line:1 char:1
+ New-GPLink -Name "GPO_Test_1" -Target "ou=Test,ou=GPO Testin ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Microsoft.GroupPolicy.GPDomain:GPDomain) [New-GPLink], ArgumentExceptio
   n
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GpoWithNameNotFound,Microsoft.GroupPolicy.Commands.NewGPLinkCommand
```

So I can see its looking at the domain that my account is on. Not the one that my computer is on.

I tried different parameters resulting in different errors.

-Domain DomA

```
New-GPLink : A referral was returned from the server. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007202B)
```

-Server DConDomA

```
New-GPLink : Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

-Domain DomA -Server DConDomA

```
New-GPLink : Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

I read that this may be because my credentials are not passing correctly to the other domain. So I tried the below:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName DConDomA -scriptblock {New-GPLink -Name "GPO_Test_1" -Target "ou=Test,ou=GPO Testing,dc=DomA" -LinkEnabled Yes} -credential $c

The "GPO_Test_1" GPO was not found in the DomC domain.
```

Again the error referencing domain my account is on ...

Adding the -Server DConDomA inside the script block still gives this error.

```
New-GPLink : Value does not fall within the expected range.
```

Tried a few different DCs (including RIDMatser on DomA and DomC) but those results in the same type of errors.

I am not sure what I am missing or doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer in is Microsoft documentation. Seems I just missed it. My Domain parameter has to be the FQDN where as I using the short name.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/grouppolicy/new-gplink?view=windowsserver2022-ps

-Domain
Specifies the domain for this cmdlet. You must specify the fully qualified domain name (FQDN) of the domain.

This note explained why it was checking the domain where my account was as well.
"If you do not specify the Domain parameter, the domain of the user that is running the current session is used. If the cmdlet is being run from a computer startup or shutdown script, the domain of the computer is used. For more information, see the Notes section in the full Help."